# Why we need http module installed to run our node js application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, httpserver

I have found so many sources for now when the first application shows this line

```
 var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World!');
}).listen(8080);
```

Just being geek, my Question is why we need server/port to listen our requests for our node js applications?
Why can't we run as localhost/application_name instead?
Why we need that?

Can anyone elobarate please?

Comment: 'Why we need http module installed to run our node js application?' We do not need to install http module it is part of NodeJs framework itself. Take a look https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

Comment: Thanks I have already read the documentation, but my main concern is can anyone eloborate that?

Comment: Browsers use HTTP. So if you want to develop a web project you need to use that protocol. If you run your project on 80 port you can use it like localhost/my_application.

Comment: Informational! Thanks can you post this as an answer

Comment: Node.js is not primarily a web server. You can *explicitly* turn it into one by using the `http` module and listening to a port of your choice. There's nothing more to it

Comment: You may see a lot of random traffic from the internet if you start running a webserver on port 80 (or even port 8080).  Keep in mind that people may start trying to talk to your computer like it is hosting a web site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Node.js® is a JavaScript runtime built on Chrome's V8 JavaScript engine. Node.js uses an event-driven, non-blocking I/O model that makes it lightweight and efficient. Node.js' package ecosystem, npm, is the largest ecosystem of open source libraries in the world.

So if you want an application which only work with bash you don't need any http modules.

Browsers use HTTP. So if you want to develop a **web application** you need to use that protocol. If you run your project on 80 port you can use it like localhost/my_application.

Simple app.js

```
var result = doSomething();
functions doSomething(){
    return "This the result";
}
console.log(result);
```

You can call it from bash. `node app.js`. But it just work and stop.

But if you want to serve this structure to WWW (which is using HTTP) you need to create server. `http` is a great and simple module for creating servers with node.js.

You can use other js files with using `require`.

app.js

```
var result = doSomething();
functions doSomething(){
    return "This the result";
}
module.exports = result;
```

server.js

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    var result = require('app.js');
    res.end(result);
}).listen(80);
```

Now you can run your server. `node server.js`

Answer (score 2):

You can run arbitrary javascript with `node`.  The code you've provided specifically sets up an http server that listens on port 8080.  You can reach that webserver from a browser on the same computer by browsing to http://localhost:8080.

Comment: Thanks I understood that portion my concern is what is the need of using http and setting explicitly port to listen our all requests?

Comment: @JayminNoob Node.js is a Javascript environment, not a web server. Using the `http` module turns it into a web server. If you don't need to serve HTTP requests then don't use that module

Comment: If you *do* use it as a webserver, then you must specify the port that the webserver listens on.

Comment: perfect please update it into answer so that it can be useful

Comment: Actually, what I said was not quite true: "If `port` is omitted or is 0, the operating system will assign an arbitrary unused port, which can be retrieved by using `server.address().port` after the `'listening'` event has been emitted."  (see: https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_port_host_backlog_callback)

Answer (score 0):

We don't need to install 'http' module in order to use it, it is already there in nodejs framework itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see output of any programming language you serve it as http because you want your browser to reach your server. Like what you do it php built in server `php -S localhost:8081` or serve it via nginx or apache

If you don't serve your JS, PHP, Python ... over http, browser will treat those files as other unsupported file like a .tar file.

Node is JavaScript environment, Not a web server. You need a server to serve your application. You may use http, https or you can create any other server that can serve your js file.

Well, I do not know if my answer is clear enough to explain but hope you will have some idea why you use http module in your nodejs application.